# cast double into short

Tags: c, casting, parallel-processing

I have an application where i HAVE to store `unsigned short` data in a `double` parallel vector to be able to easily move it around. Whenever I actually need the data, I cast them back to `unsigned short`. I know my data, although saved in a `double` vector, are well within the range of `unsigned short` i.e. the values stored are all between `0` and `2^16-1`.

Question is, since `sizeof(double) = 8` and `sizeof(unsigned short) = 2` could this cause data loss when casting? I know one problem is if the data is changed by a small bit when in `double` form, it might be rounded to another number but that is not my concern right now.

thanks

Comment: Then what *is* your concern right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to cast to assign a `short` to a `double`. There is an implicit conversion between short and double.

```
double a;
short b = 42;

a = b;  // no cast, OK as there is an implicit conversion
```

If you are using 16-bit `short` and IEEE-754 double precision `double` there is no loss of precision during the conversion.

To give some perspective, basically for single precision `float`, the first positive integer value that cannot be represented is `16777217`. So for 16-bit `short` and `double` you should be OK ;)

Comment: @webgenius `a = b` is strictly conforming but `b = a` is also strictly conforming. You can assign any arithmetic type to any arithmetic type without the need of a cast,

Answer (score 0):

If values do not exceed limits of unsigned short there won't be loss.